# best way to get realtime data to android or ios app

Tags: android, ios, ajax, api, sockets

1. i have 30 gps devices that send latitude longitude via MQTT to my server.
2. then i process data with python which listen mqtt and insert to mysql database

> what i need to do is: on my android and ios app i want to display those cordinates
> on map (1 marker for each gps device)

so i dont know what is best way to do that.

so what i think is:

1. API: create a script.php that query database and show a json format on it.

android and ios app can call it every second but will that make lot of load or idk if that is best practice.

i think similar to AJAX but im afraid this is not good idea to call every second

```
 $.ajax({url: "script.php", success: function(result){
    //do something with results
   }});
```

2. maybe to connect app directly to listen a mqtt  or tcp ip:port and publish json there.
3. some suggestion i see in internet are HTTP long-polling or something that app will stay connected and check if something change.

Comment: Remember that as soon as your app is moved off screen on ios any network connections will drop, so you will need to reestablish those connections when your app returns to the foreground. Google Firebase may work for you; Their api has an observer function and they handle all of the offline/foreground/background stuff for you

Answer (score 0):

Websockets would be a good way to implement this right? you send a stream of data from one end and the other side receives it in real time.

Comment: so i can show json there?

Comment: yes WebSocket stream can be in Json